# Complex Number solutions for a Circle

Tags: complex-numbers, circles

I have a circle of radius 5 with its center at the origin represented as $X^2+Y^2=25$. I get that it has a solution for all values ranging from $-5$ to $+5$.

My question is what does it mean when the equation returns a complex number? Example for $x=6$, I get $y = \pm i\sqrt{11}$. In doing this for all real number greater than $+5$ and less than $-5$, what is being returned/plotted and what plane is this plot on? Is this another circle on the imaginary plane, all values on the plane beyond a circle?

Comment: $$6^2+(3i)^2=36-9=27$$
So, $x=6$ implies $y=\pm i \sqrt{11}$.

Comment: Thanks for correcting Angel. It is i sqrt(11), not 3i

Comment: Welcome.  Just want to say this is a great question for which I don't have the time to write an in depth answer now, but you are asking a question I was definitely not creative or smart enough to ask before I learned the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you graph the solutions in "the plane", you are restricting yourself to look at solutions to the equation where both $x$ and $y$ are real.  You could, for example, restrict further to only allow $x$ and $y$ to be rational numbers, and think about how those points fit in with all the real solutions.

To think geometrically about non-real complex solutions, you will need more (real) dimensions!  You could restrict yourself, as it sounds like you are doing in the question, to just solutions where $x$ is real and $y$ is allowed to be complex.  Then you will need another dimension/direction for the imaginary part of $y$.  You could graph this in a "$z$" direction, so that solutions where $x>5$ not lie in the plane but above/below it.  You will find that for $|x|>5$ the solutions will be points where $x^2 - z^2 = 25$ so that if you just look at the $(x,z)$ plane the solution set will look like a hyperbola.

Probably the most interesting thing to look at is when you allow both $x$ and $y$ to be complex... but graphing this would require more dimensions.

Comment: Thank you! This and Joonas' response above answers the question that I had. I was not looking for all solutions to the equation, but what it meant for the equation to return a complex number.

Answer (score 3):

Let me denote by $A$ the circle you consider:
$$
A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2;x^2+y^2=25\}.
$$
This is the usual real circle and this is what a circle in the plane means unless something different is specifically explained.
This set consists of all pairs $(x,y)$ of numbers $x$ and $y$ which are real numbers and satisfy the equation $x^2+y^2=25$.

I stress that it is part of the very definition of $A$ that the two numbers are real.
You can ask whether a point $(x,y)$ can be in $A$ if $x=6$.
As you found out, if $x=6$ and the equation $x^2+y^2=25$ is satisfied, then $y=\pm i\sqrt{11}$.
But since $y$ is not in $\mathbb R$, the point $(x,y)$ is not in $A$.
What fails is not the equation $x^2+y^2=25$ but the condition that $x\in\mathbb R$ and $y\in\mathbb R$.
You could say that you have found a solution of the equation which is not in the plane $\mathbb R^2$.

You can also consider a different set:
$$
B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb C^2;x^2+y^2=25\}.
$$
This set looks otherwise similar to $A$, but the two numbers $x$ and $y$ can now be complex.
You can call $B$ a complexification of $A$.
Since $\mathbb R\subset\mathbb C$, we have $A\subset B$.
But there are points in $B$ which are not in $A$.
For example, the point $(6,-i\sqrt{11})$ is in $B$ — both numbers are complex and the equation is satisfied — but not in $A$ as discussed above.
However, the set $B$ is not what is usually called a circle.
It is a sort of an extension of the circle, but in a weird way.

If you identify $\mathbb C$ with $\mathbb R^2$, then $B$ is a two-dimensional surface in $\mathbb R^4$, whereas $A$ is a one-dimensional curve in $\mathbb R^2$.
Intersecting the surface with a suitable two-dimensional plane in $\mathbb R^4$ gives a circle ($B\cap\mathbb R^2=A$).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Joona's great answer, there's a nice visualization I think is worth sharing.

If we define our complex number $x$ for  $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb C^2;x^2+y^2=25\}$ as $x + iz$ we have the following:

\begin{equation}
(x+iz)^2+y^2=25
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(x^2+2xiz+i^2z^2)+y^2 = 25
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x^2+2xiz-z^2+y^2 = 25
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x^2+y^2+2xiz-z^2 = 25
\end{equation}

As we want to visualize a surface in three dimensions, we drop the imaginary part, leaving this as our circle equation:

\begin{equation}
x^2+y^2-z^2 = 25
\end{equation}

If we would to graph this, for example in Geogebra, we see the following:

[Circle equation surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FMZf.png)

Which effectively, if interesected with $z=0$, gives us our circle in $ \mathbb R^2 $:

[Surface intersected by $xy$ plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5tSB.jpg)

Then, the points where $y = 0$ intersects the surface are the ones you're looking for. [Here](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/hr5qcdv9) is the Geogebra plot if you like to play with it.

Lastly, here's how your point looks like considering the above definition:

[image]

And as Callus mentioned in his answer, we can see that the curve is indeed a hyperbola.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not get a point on another circle in complex plane  if you let $x=6$ and $y= \pm i\sqrt {11} $

The complex plane is the same as the usual $xy$ plane and you can not plot $(6, i\sqrt {11})$ on the complex plane because this is not a single point any more.

One way to find more circles is to consider $x^2+y^2 = R^2 $ where R is the radius and you can pick any $R$ and graph your circle on the $xy$ plane or as you like to call it on the complex plane.

Answer (score -2):

All the points that lie inside or on the boundary of the circle 
$$ \left\{ \ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ \colon \ x^2+ y^2 = 5^2 \ \right\} $$
lie to the right of the line 
$$ \left\{ \ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ \colon \  x = -5  \ \right\} $$
and to the left of the line
$$ \left\{ \ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ \colon \  x = 5  \ \right\}. $$
Moreover, the circle intersects the former line at the point $(-5, 0)$ and the latter one at the point $(5, 0)$.

Comment: If i take all values greater than 5 and less than 5 I will get a complex number. My question is, when I plot that x and iy what do I get? Also, where do I plot it?>

Comment: @user57074 if you take any $x$ larger than $5$ or smaller than $-5$, you'll be outside the region bounded by the two vertical lines mentioned in my answer post. So the complex value of $y$ that you'd get thus would not make any sense as far as the graph in the euclidean is concerned. In fact, the fact that $y$ becomes complex for all $x < -5$ and for all $x>5$ tells us that there are no actual points (either inside or on the boundary) of the circle that lie outside the region bounded between the vertical lines $x = -5$ and $x = 5$. Hope that helps.